# What does a phrase "Better by you" mean

Tags: meaning

What does "Better by you" phrase mean in the title of a Judas Priest song "Better By You Better Than Me".

Comment: Lyrics are typically mere interpretations; often times even the lyricist(s) don't intend on having one single meaning.

Comment: It’s not a Judas Priest song (originally), but a Spooky Tooth song. And at face value, it means absolutely nothing at all—it’s complete and utter nonsense. Any meaning it may have can only be found out through literary interpretation of the lyrics, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Spooky Tooth! Haven't heard that name in many, many years @Janus Bahs Jacquet. As a young teenager I had one of their LPs, *She Broke My Heart So I Busted Her Jaw*. Man, but those were the daze! when titles used to have a meaning!

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, thanks for introducing me a "new" band. I thought the song didn't sound much like Judas Priest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.  It is a phrase made up i  a song by a rock group.  It means whatever you want it to.  It probably rhymed and had the right mumber of beats.

Comment: Not true. Its a guy telling his friend that its easier for the friend to explain what he did during the war than for him to explain it himself.  "you can say what I only can see. Its better by you, better than me"